# Migrate from xml with two attributes as condition

Tags: migrations, feeds

I have a problem with drupal migrate, i'm trying migrate content with this xpath:

```
item_xpath = '/import/content/contentInstance[@contentTypeId=\'ac1ssss___\' @window=\'blank\]';
```

when i execute drush ms return 0 results, however if i use only one condition in item_xpath:

```
item_xpath = '/import/content/contentInstance[@contentTypeId=\'ac1ssss___\']';
```

Return 15 results

```
'/import/content/contentInstance[**@contentTypeId=\'ac1ssss___\' @window=\'blank\]';
```

Return 10 results

The xml have content with two attributes, not migrate allows two conditions as attribute?

Thanks for all.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is a Drupal question (XPath is its own language, Drupal doesn't change it). Have you tested your expressions outside Drupal? Do they work? Have you read through examples, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029232/how-to-select-two-attributes-from-the-same-node-with-one-expression-in-xpath)?

Comment: Sorry item_xpath is:

item_xpath = '/import/content/contentInstance[@contentTypeId=\'ac1ssss___\'  and @window=\'blank]'; 

but does not works

Comment: And it does work outside Drupal when you just run that expression against your test string? That's very strange. I'd say you've found a bug in the migrate module

Comment: Yes, if i use same files with xpath evaluator works but drupal migrate doesnt works , maybe are a bug ?

Comment: Yes if your XPath expression is valid, and it doesn't work in a particular module, that's got to be a bug in the module (or PHP's XPath processor). I would double and triple check, though, according to the link I posted above your expression isn't a valid way to query by multiple attributes on the same element

Comment: This expression isnt valid ? 

 item_xpath = '/import/content/contentInstance[@contentTypeId=\'ac1ssss___\' and @window=\'blank]';

i view in your link this expression , what is correct expression?

Comment: I don't know what your test string looks like so I couldn't possibly say - we're just Drupal focused here anyway, if you need help with xpath expressions please ask on Stack Overflow. Once you've confirmed your xpath expression is definitely correct, if it still doesn't work inside the migrate module, and there's nothing in their documentation to explain why, I'd be tempted to open a bug report

Comment: In my xpath evaluator return values , same xpath in migrate nothing ! i will open a bug in migrate module, thanks for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention what XML source plugin you're using - is it MigrateSourceXML? If so, note that ([as documented](https://www.drupal.org/node/1152156#MigrateSourceXML)), it does not read in the entire XML file thus general-purpose xpath is not available, it implements a limited subset of xpath syntax for selecting the items to import. You should use [MigrateSourceMultiItems](https://www.drupal.org/node/1152156#MigrateSourceMultiItems) when you need full xpath syntax.